# How to archive git status output?

Tags: git, archive, status

I need to archive some changes which are shown by `git status` command and keep all the paths, so I can copy it, unarchive and commit on my local machine. I know that `git archive` command exists but how to use it with `git status`?

Comment: why dont you just tar your whole working copy and untar it at home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git-archive is meant to archive the whole project, and works only with a commit/tag id.
What you want to do is:

```
git diff > patchfile
```

and

```
patch -p1 < patchfile
```

on your local machine.